# Set $_SESSION into input value using Twig

Tags: php, session, twig

I am making a registration form and I want the page to be reset in case of incorrectly entered data, but I don't want also to disappear the entered data. The problem is I don't know how to do this using Twig. So I do something like this:

```
$_SESSION['fr_firstName'] = $firstName;
```

And then I want to enter this name inside the input value. In my index.php I have:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once 'lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
    Twig_Autoloader::register();

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('temp');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

    if(isset($_SESSION['fr_firstName']))
    {

    }

    echo $twig->render('index.html', array(
        'fr_firstName' => ''
    ));
?>
```

In my index.html is:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="{{ fr_firstName }}">
<input type="submit" class="reg" value="Sign Up"/>
</form>
```

And in my register.php is:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    //another thinks
    $_SESSION['fr_firstName'] = $firstName;
    //another thinks
    require_once "connect.php";
    //another thinks
    $connection = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
    //another thinks
    header('Location: index.php');
    //another thinks
```

ok and here is my question. How to set (in index.php) $_SESSION['fr_firstName'] into input value in index.html?

I mean something like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['fr_firstName']))
{
echo $twig->render('index.html', array(
        'fr_firstName' => $_SESSION['fr_firstName']
    ));
}
```

Comment: I am using just twing component, not symfony

Answer (score 2):

Unsure what's not working for you, but instead of using an if to surround your render, you should go with

```
    echo $twig->render('index.html', [
        'fr_firstName' => isset($_SESSION['fr_firstName']) ? $_SESSION['fr_firstName'] : '',
    ]);
```

---

If you are using `PHP 7.X.X` version u could use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

```
    echo $twig->render('index.html', [
        'fr_firstName' => $_SESSION['fr_firstName'] ?? '',
        'fr_Name'      => $_SESSION['fr_Name'] ?? '',
        'fr_Email'     => $_SESSION['fr_Email'] ?? '',
        /** etc.... **/
    ]);
```

---

Another approach would be to pass the whole `session`-array towards twig and use the filter `default` inside the template e.g.

```
echo $twig->render('index.html', array_merge([
    'some_var' => 'var',
    'foo'      => 'bar',
], $_SESSION));
```

```html
<input name="fr_firstName" value="{{ fr_firstName | default('') }}" />
```

---

If you really wanted to use the full `if` notation, U would go with something like the following

```
$parms = [];
if (isset($_SESSION['fr_firstName'])) $parms['fr_firstName'] = $_SESSION['fr_firstName'];
if (isset($_SESSION['fr_Name'])) $parms['fr_Name'] = $_SESSION['fr_Name'];
if (isset($_SESSION['fr_Email'])) $parms['fr_Email'] = $_SESSION['fr_Email'];

echo $twig->render('index.html', $parms);
```

Comment: can I do this also on if?

Comment: You could but then you would be creating duplicate code `if (condition) { echo $twig->render(....); }else{ $twig->render(...); }`. Also, this approach is much cleaner when you have multiple inputs.See updated answer

Comment: One question more. Could I use "if" inside array? I mean instead of `echo $twig->render('index.html', ['fr_firstName' => isset($_SESSION['fr_firstName']) ? $_SESSION['fr_firstName'] : '',]);` something like: `echo $twig>render('index.html', ['fr_firstName' => if(isset(...)){...},]);`?